# About the in operator of TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the TypeScript documentation site

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

it has sample code as follows:

```js
type EventConfig<Events extends { kind: string }> = {
    [E in Events as E["kind"]]: (event: E) => void;
}
 
type SquareEvent = { kind: "square", x: number, y: number };
type CircleEvent = { kind: "circle", radius: number };
 
type Config = EventConfig<SquareEvent | CircleEvent>
```

what's the meaning of `E in Events`?

Please help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` keyword is used for a few different things in TypeScript, but this particular one is using `in` to select each individual member of the union type `Events` in order to map it.

`EventConfig` is a mapped type that uses the members of the union to define the properties of an object type. (We know that because of the form it's in, `{ KeyType: ValueType }`.) `E in Events` defines the `E` identifier, saying "for each union member, use `E` to refer to that individual member's type" for the purposes of defining each property in the object type being defined. Given the example `EventConfig<SquareEvent | CircleEvent>`, that means that `E` is *each individual member* of the union (`SquareEvent` and, separately, `CircleEvent`) during the mapping operation (in contrast, `Events` is the *union* of those members). It's *almost* like a loop through the union members (though it isn't a loop).

After `E in Events`, the `as E["kind"]` part of the property key expression says "And from `E`, take the type of the `kind` property as the property key."

With that in mind, let's look at the overall property definition part of that mapped type:

```
{
    [E in Events as E["kind"]]: (event: E) => void;
}
```

For `EventConfig<SquareEvent | CircleEvent>`, that will be evaluated with `E` being `SquareEvent` and also `E` being `CircleEvent`, where each of them defines one property in the resulting object type. Let's expand that, replacing `E` with each of the union members:

```
{
    [SquareEvent["kind"]]: (event: SquareEvent) => void;
    [CircleEvent["kind"]]: (event: CircleEvent) => void;
}
```

we can go further, though, because we can resolve the type of `SquareEvent["kind"]` to the string literal type `"square"` and `CircleEvent["kind"]` to `"circle"`, giving us:

```
{
    square: (event: SquareEvent) => void;
    circle: (event: CircleEvent) => void;
}
```